# How to split a cmis url into repository path and path with respect to repository?

Tags: sharepoint, alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I'm a GSoC'13 intern. I'm working on developing a CMIS UCP for Apache OpenOffice.
I wanted to know how to divide a url into its parts.
To fill the session parameters I need the url + path of the object in repo. separately.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Normally you just want the URL of the AtomPub (or other) binding endpoint, then you get everything from that. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I dont want to ask for atompub url and the path of the object separately. I want it in a single path. for example a folder stored on: http://localhost:8080/inmemory/atom with path /My_Folder-0-0 in repository A1, should be represented by http://localhost:8080/inmemory/atom/A1/My_Folder-0-0 . So, I want to make use of an existing scheme, or define one myself.

Comment: How would the user know such a (possibly made up) URL thought? Surely all they'd know is the CMIS endpoint, and possibly the path?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the path of an object, you can retrieve it using getObjectByPath, which is a method on org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session.

If you have an object and you want to know its path, you can call the object's getPaths() method, which returns a list of paths for the object (in repositories that support multi-filing, documents can have multiple paths, but folders can never be multi-filed).

The actual URL you would construct to navigate directly to the object using its path is repository-specific, unless you are using the browser binding (new in CMIS 1.1). But there aren't any production implementations of the CMIS 1.1 browser binding yet.

Comment: Is there a way to request the repository to return the url scheme it follows?

Comment: Using the Atom Pub binding you can invoke the repository's service URL, then inspect the cmisra:uritemplate elements that come back. There is one with a cmisra:type of "objectbypath" that might be useful to you for this.